# Android - Admob SurfaceView

Tags: android, admob

I am new to android development, but I am trying to add admob to my app which is using a surfaceview (panelView - GameView).

I tried following http://rx-games.com/admob-adverts-on-surfaceview-no-xml-tutorial/ but I must be doing something wrong, as rl.addView(panelView); adds a nullPointerException. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14ded47ad3779e");
    panelView = (GameView) findViewById(R.id.gameScreen);

    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
    rl.addView(panelView);
    rl.addView(adView);

    setContentView(rl);

    threadView = panelView.getThread();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inflating the GameView class from an xml layout and add it to a root View that is not the one defined in that same xml. You have two options:

1. You create your SurfaceView entirely in Java (as in the example you posted)
2. You include the AdView in the xml layout (I would prefer this option over the other one)

If you name the xml file `game_layout.xml`, you use it as:

```
setContentView(R.layout.game_layout.xml);
```

**game_layout.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
  <com.google.ads.AdView 
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_id"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBotom="true"
    />
  <your.package.GameView 
    android:id="@+id/gameScreen"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/adView"
  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Like I said, I am very new... I have already created the gameview class with 4000+ lines of code. How would I invoke this and the adView in the xml? If you know a tutorial for this, that works. I don't think I understand how views work...

Comment: @Tom see the example in the updated response. Regarding to tutorials, I would suggest you to start by reading the dev guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html

Comment: I marked you as accepted answer, but I'm still having issues... Now it's giving me a runtime error and a blank screen. Thanks for the help this far. I'm in the military and teaching myself in what spare time I can get.

Comment: I really suggest you then to start with some more modest projects. 4K LOCs are way too many for a beginner project.

Comment: I know how to program and I know how logic works, I just don't understand the views and all that android specific stuff. -The app in reference is in the google market under "Joey Ant"

Comment: What I mean is that you don't need very complicated views to grasps those concepts. Once you figure it out, you can go back to your code.